# Multiple tracks audio

Tags: audio, arduino, sd-card, mixer

I am looking for some easy way to play an audio by Arduino Uno. At the beginning my project contains few LED's, buttons, motor, and speaker. This speaker should play the sample of engine.

This project was very easy. I have decided to use YX5100 or YX5300. At all after few tests my project got a little bit more complicated. With this engine sound I want to mix few other samples like horn, wheels, and other sounds. Maximum 4 sounds together.

My first idea was easy - buy 4 YX5300 and connect it together. But how to connect it with one speaker. I found some small mixer. Great but the problems started from that moment. How to read only one sd card by every controllers...

At all I am looking for some great method to play few samples together, depends from properties, by Arduino. I will be glad for some help or ideas how to polish my plan.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is the [Sparkfun WAV Trigger](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13660). The route you are trying has multiple hardware limitations. This board can do everything you described and more.

Comment: Thank you! I think it is what I am looking for but at all this module is too big for my model. At all thank you for this link :D